# Перехват вызова метода

Tags: php, ооп

Есть интерфейс

```
interface TestInterface {

    public function test();
    public function test2();

}
```

Есть несколько родительских классов

```
class ParentClass1 implements TestInterface {

    public $child = false;

    public function test() {
        if (!$this->child) {
            return 'fail';
        }
        echo 'test1';
    }

    public function test2() {
        echo 'test2';
    }

}

class ParentClass2 implements TestInterface {

    public $child = false;

    public function test() {
        if (!$this->child) {
            return 'fail';
        }
        echo 'test2';
    }

    public function test2() {
        echo 'test2';
    }

}
```

И есть рандомные наследуемые классы

```
class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass1 {

    public $child = 1;

}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass2 {

    public $child = 2;

}
```

Сам по себе родительский класс может быть создан (не абстрактный), и может быть вызван метод test2. 
Чтоб разрешить выполнение метода test только для дочерних элементов, приходится в каждый родительский класс вставлять этот костыль

```
if (!$this->child) {
    return 'fail';
}
```

В приложении естественно, подобных классов гораздо больше чем 2, приходится повторять один и тот же костыль в многих классах. Была мысль, сделать общую абстракцию для всех родительских классов, реализовать в нёй метод __call, сделать методы protected, и отлавливать вызовы методов. Но php ругается (т.к. интерфейс, а значит только public). 
Есть какие либо идеи, как отлавливать вызовы методов другим способом ?

Comment: несколько странно поддерживать интерфейс и запрещать вызывать методы при этом.

Comment: Наверное придётся сделать родительские классы абстрактными, а разрешенный метод статичным. Не совсем хорошо вписывается в структуру приложения, ну да ладно